# RxScala recursive stream with timeout

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-scala

I'm trying to recursively define an observable that either emits items from a subject or, if a certain amount of time passes, a default value, in this case I'm using the timer's default value of zero. I'm using RxScala and have begun with the following code:

```
val s = PublishSubject[Int]()

def o: Observable[Unit] = {
  val timeout = Observable.timer(1 second)
  Observable.amb(s, timeout)
    .first
    .concatMap((v) => {
      println(v)
      o
    })
}

ComputationScheduler().createWorker.schedule {
  var value = 0
  def loop(): Unit = {
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    s.onNext(value + 1)
    value += 1
    loop()
  }
  loop()
}

o.toBlocking.last
```

This seems like it should work, but the output is confusing. Every other sequence of zeros contains two instead of the expected four. Two zeros are emitted and the remaining three seconds elapses, but without output.

```
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
3
0
0
4
0
0
0
0
5
0
0
6
0
0
0
0
7
0
0
8
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is puzzling indeed! So here's a theory:

1. In truth, your code is producing 4 ticks every 5 seconds rather than 5.
2. There is a race condition on the 4th, one, won first by the timeout, then the worker, then the timeout, etc.

So, instead of the sequence being 00001 002 00003... look at it as 0000 1002 0000...

So you might have 2 separate problems here and I can't do much without fiddling with it, but things you can try:

1. Add also a serial number to o(), so you can see which timouts are not winning the race.
2. Change the values from 1 and 5 seconds to some that are not multiple of each other, like 1.5 and 5. This might help you take one problem out and focus on the other.
3. Put an external, unrelated worker to print "----" every second. Start it after 0.3 seconds or so. Might give you a better idea of where the divide is.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll play with some more this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring your code to the following generates the expected result (on my machine):

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s = PublishSubject[Int]()

    val timeout = Observable.timer(1 second)

    def o: Observable[Unit] = {
      Observable.amb(s, timeout).first
        .concatMap((v) => {
          println(v)
          o
        })
    }

    var value = 0
    NewThreadScheduler().createWorker.scheduleRec {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      value += 1
      s.onNext(value)
    }

    o.toBlocking.last
  }
}
```

Notice the switch to the NewThreadScheduler and the use of the scheduleRec method as opposed to manual recursive scheduling.